# Custom performance counter on azure node.js worker role

Tags: node.js, azure

I am building a node.js project on Azure worker role using socket.io, and wanted to monitor some counters like request count and success count. Does Azure node.js lib provides such support or is there any 3rd part library I can leverage to create and log custom performance counters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[measured](https://github.com/felixge/node-measured) supports several different kind of metrics (gages, counters, meters, histograms).

Others can be found here: https://npmjs.org/